# How to set original color of markers in plot legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

I tried to make a plot markers manually as follows

```
PointLegend[ {Black} , {"a"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]}], 
     FaceForm[Transparent], Rectangle[]}]}]
```

However, the color of resulting legend looks a bit whitened so in this case the resulting color looks grey instead of black.

Why was the color changed and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the box form of your legend (using `ToBoxes`) you will see that the `GraphicsBox` representing your marker has the option

```
DefaultBaseStyle -> {"Graphics", {AbsolutePointSize[6]}, 
 Directive[EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], GrayLevel[0]]], 
 PointSize[0.5], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], GrayLevel[0]]}
```

Note that it includes an `Opacity[0.3]` in the `EdgeForm`, as `Opacity` is a separate directive, setting the color to `Black` is insufficient to override it. So, instead, use

```
EdgeForm[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1]}]
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

A quick check by running `ToBoxes`on your example showed a couple of `Opacity[0.3]` in the output (not sure why this is done), causing the ligther color. This solved the problem for me:

```
PointLegend[{Black}, {"a"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
       Opacity[1]}], FaceForm[White], Rectangle[]}]}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 200]
```

Comment: Beet you by a couple of minutes, but +1 for the correct answer.